# Async method that doesn't use an await internally, so is synchronous

Tags: c#, async-await

I have heard a lot about `Async` and `await`, and have a basic understanding of it, but my knowledge is limited.

It is currently scattered all over a project I am working on, and I am trying to understand the implication of having `async` methods that are not `awaited`

eg something like this:

```
public async Task<int> getNumber()
{
     return await getFirstNumber();    
}

public async Task<int> getFirstNumber()
{
     return 1;
}
```

Note in the example above, both methods are `async` - but only getNumber calls await.

Is this a problem, and if so, what is the problem?

How about if `getFirstNumber()` did a database call or some other I/O, or something else that could be slow?

Is this something I should avoid at all costs, or is it sometimes ok, and if so, under what circumstances?

EDIT:
Async/await warnings are not active of my version of VS, so my code runs fine with the above.

Comment: If you don't use await on getFirstNumber remove the async..

Comment: `getFirstNumber` should be giving you a warning indicating that it's a bad practice. If `getFirstNumber` does IO or otherwise has something to `await` then, and only then, mark it `async` and then `await` what needs to be `awaited`.

Comment: @Max I am not asking if I should remove it, I am asking what the effect of having this would be

Comment: `async` is meaningless without `await`. `async` doesn't really do anything by itself. `await` is what creates `AsyncStateMachine`. If you don't have any `await` then the method call is synchronous and works as any other method.

Comment: to clarify the nomenclature: you aren't talking about an "Async method that is not awaited" (title) - ultimately it is the caller that decides whether or not it gets awaited. What you mean is: "Async method that doesn't use an `await` internally, so is synchronous" - which is a very valid question. Note: you *might* want to think about `ValueTask<T>` here - it is *designed* for scenarios where the return value is *usually* synchronous and has much lower overhead in the sync path.

Comment: "I have heard a lot about Async and await, and have a basic understanding of it, but my knowledge is limited." That's true for 90% of us. We just don't admit it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only a problem because the `async`/`await` pattern has some overhead associated with it which isn't useful in this case. Instead, you can just return your task directly.

```
public Task<int> getFirstNumber()
{
     return Task.FromResult(1);
}
```

Remember using `async/await` is only an *implementation detail* and doesn't affect the "interface" or public-facing contract of your method. So if some day you need `getFirstNumber()` to do a database call, you are free to switch back to using `async`/`await` without breaking the expectations set by your method signature.

In case you're interested, here's the IL code for getFirstNumber with the async/await pattern:

```
getFirstNumber:
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldarg.0     
IL_0008:  stfld       UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>4__this
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     
IL_000E:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Int32>.Create
IL_0013:  stfld       UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>t__builder
IL_0018:  ldloc.0     
IL_0019:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_001A:  stfld       UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>1__state
IL_001F:  ldloc.0     
IL_0020:  ldfld       UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>t__builder
IL_0025:  stloc.1     
IL_0026:  ldloca.s    01 
IL_0028:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_002A:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Int32>.Start<<getFirstNumber>d__1>
IL_002F:  ldloc.0     
IL_0030:  ldflda      UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>t__builder
IL_0035:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Int32>.get_Task
IL_003A:  ret         

<getFirstNumber>d__1.MoveNext:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>1__state
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0009:  stloc.1     
IL_000A:  leave.s     IL_0024
IL_000C:  stloc.2     
IL_000D:  ldarg.0     
IL_000E:  ldc.i4.s    FE 
IL_0010:  stfld       UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>1__state
IL_0015:  ldarg.0     
IL_0016:  ldflda      UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>t__builder
IL_001B:  ldloc.2     
IL_001C:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Int32>.SetException
IL_0021:  nop         
IL_0022:  leave.s     IL_0039
IL_0024:  ldarg.0     
IL_0025:  ldc.i4.s    FE 
IL_0027:  stfld       UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>1__state
IL_002C:  ldarg.0     
IL_002D:  ldflda      UserQuery+<getFirstNumber>d__1.<>t__builder
IL_0032:  ldloc.1     
IL_0033:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Int32>.SetResult
IL_0038:  nop         
IL_0039:  ret         

<getFirstNumber>d__1.SetStateMachine:
IL_0000:  ret         

<getFirstNumber>d__1..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  ret
```

And here's what it looks like using Task.FromResult():

```
getFirstNumber:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  call        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult<Int32>
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  br.s        IL_000A
IL_000A:  ldloc.0     
IL_000B:  ret
```

Comment: so you mean that the code will run fine and there will be no adverse affects except for the slight overhead?

Comment: @Alex: Yeah. Besides a slight performance hit, the only difference you'd see is that the stack trace would be a little different if an exception was thrown in your method.

Comment: @Alex Whether or not its a problem will depend radically on what the method actually does, and what it's expected to do.  It's completely incorrect to say that the only possible issue is a very small overhead, that's just the problem *with the one snippet that you showed*, but of course that snippet isn't actually doing any meaningful work.

Comment: @Servy That's interesting. Can you provide an example of what a non-awaiting async method could do that would cause problems besides performance overhead?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior The most common/significant would be the method running synchronously when the author *thinks* it's running asynchronously.

Comment: @Servy: So your concern is not using `async` without `await`, so much as the possibility that the method might be doing something synchronously that it should be doing asynchronously. Is that right? Maybe the UI code assumes this method will act asynchronously, and ends up allowing this method to block the UI thread because it's performing a long-running operation synchronously?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior That's the most likely (and one of the more significant) problem resulting from having an `async` method with no `await`,  yes.  The number of situation in which the behavior of an `async` method without any `await` calls is...very uncommon, so uncommon that C# felt the need to add a warning for that exact case because it was considered so unlikely to be the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Some people said that the Task in your `getFirstNumber` method is useless, I would go even further and say that, in both your method, waiting for the task is not bringing you any benefit.
The idea of waiting for a Task is usually related to the fact that:

- you need the result of that task (for `Task<TResult>`), **or**;
- you want to make sure the task completely executes so you can move on to the next statement;

I don't see this being the case in your example. You could simply write:

```
public Task<int> getNumber()
{
     return getFirstNumber();    
}

public Task<int> getFirstNumber()
{
     return Task.FromResult(1);
}
```

In real world scenario, imagine a Repository class that uses Entity Framework to access the data layer. There is nothing wrong on having a method like this:

```
public Task<int> GetLatestUserId ()
{
    var resultTask = db.Users.Select(u => u.Id).OrderByDesc(id => id).FirstAsync();
    return resultTask;
}
```

The caller of this method would probably have to wait this returned task in order to use the internet value ( `int I'd = await repository.GetLatestUserId()`) and consequently, it would have to be an `async` method.

Comment: The one weird aspect with the last piece of code you reference is that if an exception is thrown inside of `FirstAsync()` then your stack trace may or may not skip over the call to `GetLatestUserId()` (depending on whether the exception was thrown prior to its asynchronous operation), which could make debugging a little more bizarre. Likewise, if you have a try/catch around the call to `.FirstAsync()`, it'll catch exceptions thrown prior to actually performing something asynchronous, but not those thrown after the asynchronous call.